# How to create a loading spinner method that include display:Block display: none using Selenium C#?

Tags: c#, selenium, kendo-ui

I can not catch the loader in my test. I need to create a method that will help me to see when the loader is no longer visible. I can not select any of the page elements because of this problem.

Code attempted:

```
public static void SeeNoLoaderInQD() 
{ 
    Actor.Wait.UntilElementIsNotDisplayed(Elements.QDLoader); 
    Assert.IsTrue(Elements.SeeException.Count == 0); 
}
```

[image: SnapShort]

Comment: can you add code you have tried?

Comment: public static void SeeNoLoaderInQD()
        {
            Actor.Wait.UntilElementIsNotDisplayed(Elements.QDLoader);
            Assert.IsTrue(Elements.SeeException.Count == 0);
        }

Answer (score 2):

I would try something like this:

```
public static void WaitForElementAttributeValue(this IWebDriver driver, By by, string attribute, string value)
{
    var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
    wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(by).GetAttribute(attribute).Contains(value));
}
```

You can call this method for your scenario like this:

```
driver.WaitForElementAttributeValue(By.Id("line-scale-loader"), "style", "display: none;");
```

When calling this method, you are telling WebDriver to wait until the WebElement's `style` attribute value is equal to `display: none;` meaning the loader is no longer visible.

Comment: This will only work if the specific element located contains this attribute. What if one of the parent elements have "display: none" which causes the desired element to not be displayed? Why not use the built in `ExpectedConditions` and handle both/all cases?

Comment: Based on the HTML sample that was provided, the load spinner seems to appear at the top of the DOM so there was not risk of parent elements being hidden. `ExpectedConditions` is deprecated in .NET bindings and requires `DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers` to use now, so I try to provide an example that does not require adding any other packages if possible.

Answer (score 1):

To check if a page is loaded, I usually check 3 criteria, those are:-

- Is page ready?
- Are ajax calls completed?
- Is the spinner/loader invisible?

Sample code,

```
    public static void WaitForPageToLoad(IWebDriver driver)
    {           
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
        wait.Until(driver =>
        {               
            bool isPageReady = (bool)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).
                ExecuteScript("return document.readyState == 'complete'");               
            bool isAjaxFinished = (bool)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).
            ExecuteScript("return jQuery.active == 0");
            bool isLoaderInvisible = (bool)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).
                ExecuteScript("return $('#line-scale-loader').is(':visible') == false");
            return isPageReady && isAjaxFinished && isLoaderInvisible;
        });          
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium has `ExpectedConditions` built in that you can use with `WebDriverWait` to handle situations like this. It might be the case that your wait for invisible is firing and passing before the loader becomes visible which could cause later actions to fail because the loader appears later. You might add a wait for visible and then a wait for invisible.

```
By qdLoaderLocator = By.Id("line-scale-loader");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(qdLoaderLocator));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(qdLoaderLocator));
```

---

Side note... don't use Asserts like

```
Assert.IsTrue(Elements.SeeException.Count == 0);
```

because when they fail, you will get

```
Expected: true
Actual: false
```

which doesn't tell you anything. Instead use one of the below options.

```
Assert.Zero(Elements.SeeException.Count, "Verify no exceptions");
Assert.AreEqual(0, Elements.SeeException.Count, "Verify no exceptions");
```

Now you will get

```
Verify no exceptions
Expected: 0
Actual: 2
```

In this case it might not seem terribly useful but you at least get more information than just true/false. When you start comparing strings, numbers, etc. it will be a LOT more useful.