# C# Selenium wait until element display is equal to none - works only on debug

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

I'm facing some trouble while automating a form that contains a div with `style="display: none;"`
It has an Id, but I can't use it without the debug.

The issue is: there is a dropdown that loads its options only after this "load image" goes away.
So I tried many solutions and every single option from the `SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers` ('cause the old is going to be deprecated in C#).

The closer I get from a solution was this code here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58100882/11670912

Here is my code:

```
<div id="updateProgress" style="display: none;" role="status" aria-hidden="true" xpath="1">

            <div id="divLoading" style="position: absolute; z-index: 10; left: 450px; top: 90px;">
                <img id="ajaxLoadNotificationImage" src="../images/ajax-loader-center.gif" alt="[image]">
            </div>

</div>
```

--

```
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(WebDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(90));
            wait.Until(WebDriver =>
            {
                return WebDriver.FindElement(By.Id("updateProgress")).GetAttribute("style").Contains("display: none;");
            });
```

I've tried these as well:

```
wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeSelected(By.XPath(profilePage.LoadingStateImg.GetAttribute("style").Contains("display: none;").ToString())));
```

```
wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(By.XPath(profilePage.LoadingStateImg.GetAttribute("style").Contains("display: none;").ToString())));
```

Not listed above, but I've tried:
- InvisibilityOfElementWithText
- StalenessOf
- ElementIsVisible
- TextToBePresentInElementValue

It seems doesn't even get into these lines of code while running.
The debug shows the text ok with the attribute "display: none;" and goes to the selection of the required dropdown.
I don't want to use `Thread.Sleep()`, but so far it is the only thing that works.
*(`Tread.Sleep` works, but obviously I'm not trying to get into it, because the page is so slow that I'd need to 40-60 seconds...)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If i understand correctly, you have this div that when it disappears, the list loads? maybe you should just wait for it to "not be visible" instead of depending on the "style" attribute.

Comment: I've tried this as well:
     
`wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//div[@id='updateProgress'][@style='display: none;']")));`

It didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it by myself.
It was needed to check at first if the element was visible (By locator), so I could check then if it was not visible. The element probably blinks at page before being shown definitely on page:

```
WebDriver.WaitForElementIsVisible(By.Id(profilePage.LoadingStateLocator));
WebDriver.WaitForElementIsNotVisible(profilePage.LoadingStateImg);
```